# Почему не применяется анимация?

Tags: html, css

К кнопке с классом scroll-down не хочет применяться анимация. Цвет меняется мгновенно, хотя все должно происходить плавно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML

```
<div class="container introduction">
        <img class="illustration" src="img/content/illustration.svg" alt="ELEMENT CUSTOMIZE">
        <div class="scroll scroll-down">
            <img src="img/icons/arrow-down.svg" alt="" class="arrow-down arrow">
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */

/*# style.scss */

*, *:before, *:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(72.21deg, #141812 -0.34%, #161422 28.25%, #1C0D0D 68.52%, #1A0623 96.34%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 1164px;
  height: 910px;
}
.container .scroll {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #A00BC5 0%, #1B5454 100%);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  transition: all 3s 0s ease-out;
}
.container .scroll:hover {
  transition: background 3s 0s ease-out;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #D012FF 0%, #0B9191 100%);
}
.container .scroll .arrow {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
}

.introduction {
  margin-top: 55px;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: end;
}
```

Comment: Градиенты анимировать невозможно, можно только попытаться придумать какой-нибудь костыль https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212

Comment: Градиенты смена цветов не анимируется. На данном сайте предоставлена информация как это можно сделать с помощью теней(box-shadow): http://css.yoksel.ru/animation-for-gradients/